# Do You Implement hook_help()?

Tags: hooks

How should I implement [hook_help()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!help!help.api.php/function/hook_help/7)?  Should I output the content of the README.txt file, or inline text?

Comment: Isnt this more of discussion...

Comment: This does border on "not constructive" at the moment, but I think that this question can be reworked to make it good a fit for the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this really depends on what you need.

For page specific help, returning translated text does appear to be the norm from the modules I have surveyed, and does follow the [Help text standard (for core and contrib)](http://drupal.org/node/632280).

For the text on the admin/help page, I think that using the README.txt is best, since that should really be a "one-stop-shop" for help with the module, and you don't want to have to track your changes in two places.  It is also a pain to format that much text with code.  However, this does make translation hard.

I have not seen a "standard" way to handle the README.txt.  If you look at the [Module documentation guidelines](http://drupal.org/node/161085#hook_help), they give this example for Drupal 6:

```
function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case 'admin/help#mymodule':
      // Return a line-break version of the module README.txt
      return filter_filter('process', 1, NULL, file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . "/README.txt") );
  }
}
```

and there is a comment for a Drupal 7 version:

```
function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case 'admin/help#mymodule':
      // Return a line-break version of the module README.txt
      return check_markup(file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . "/README.txt") );
  }
}
```

Personally, the version I like what Features does:

```
function features_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case 'admin/help#features':
      $output = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'features') .'/README.txt');
      return module_exists('markdown') ? filter_xss_admin(module_invoke('markdown', 'filter', 'process', 0, -1, $output)) : '<pre>'. check_plain($output) .'</pre>';
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer inline text, because it's really hard to parse README.txt if you want to show different help for different paths.

```
function hook_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case 'admin/help':
      return 'Hello Admin!';

    case 'admin/structure/block':
      return 'Hello Block!';
  }
}
```